# Different numbering for algorithms and procedures

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am using `algorithmicx` package in LaTeX to write an algorithm and a procedure in my LaTeX file. I want LaTeX to number the procedures differently, but the numbering is the same as algorithms. Is there any way to have an independent numbering for the procedures?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]                
\caption{Set $S$} \label{alg001}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $S \gets \emptyset$;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \Procedure{Proc}{$A,B$}
     \State $T \gets \emptyset$;
 \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \caption{The Procedure}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be done better, but the idea should be clear. We define the second algorithm-like float.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}




\newfloat{procedure}{htbp}{loa}
\floatname{procedure}{Procedure} %It may be done better


\begin{algorithm}[h]                
\caption{Set $S$} \label{alg001}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $S \gets \emptyset$;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

%\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
%\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{procedure}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \Procedure{Proc}{$A,B$}
     \State $T \gets \emptyset$;
 \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \caption{The Procedure}
%\end{algorithm}
\end{procedure}


\end{document}
```

[image]